# the phrase 'based on'

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage

Can we use the phrase 'based on' at the beginning of a sentence?

Based on the plant organ, species diversity in the twig organ is indicated as higher than in other organs.

Comment: Why do you think you wouldn't be able to?

Comment: The question is on-topic, but I've downvoted it because you haven't explained the premise of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you most certainly can.

> i.e. "Based on our research, we estimate you’d be able to do all this on your smartphone, every day..."